# Help in finding a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a definite integral from an answer key. I just need help on how the answer got from the first step to the final step. The steps are:
\begin{align}&
\int_0^\infty x^{10}\begin{pmatrix}\frac 45\exp\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-7x}6\end{bmatrix}+\frac 35\exp\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-13x}{12}\end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix} \,dx\\&=\frac 4 5 \cdot10!\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac 6 7 \end{pmatrix}^{11} +\frac 3 5 \cdot10!\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac {12}{13} \end{pmatrix}^{11} \\&=10! \cdot 0.396
\end{align}

My question again, is how did the answer transit from the first line to the second line?

Comment: Integration by parts, ten times (or rather one integration by parts to show a reduction formula)

Comment: i get the integration by parts 10 times, no worries, but could you guide me on the reduction formula? @mixedmath

Comment: [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction formula [mixedmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/mixedmath) has referenced is the following $$\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-ax} \, dx = \frac{n}{a} \int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-ax} \, dx,$$ where $a>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. You can arrive at it using integration by parts: $$\begin{align} \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-ax} \, dx & = x^n \frac{e^{-ax}}{-a} \bigg\vert_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} n x^{n-1} \frac{e^{-ax}}{-a} \, dx \\ & = \frac{n}{a} \int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-ax} \, dx. \end{align}$$ Applying it iteratively one arrives at $$\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-ax} \, dx = \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: I have always known this approach to be an "integration by parts" approach but not "reduction formula". Doing so recursively provides the final step, which is what I exactly need.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If, as suggested, you integrate by parts and work the recurrence relation, you should arrive to 
$$\int_0^\infty x^{n} e^{-k x}dx=k^{-(n+1)} \Gamma (n+1)$$ as log as $\Re(n)>-1$ and $\Re(k)>0$

Comment: So this is what he meant when he said Gamma...I have been using "factorial" for over 10 years and only "Gamma" for less than 3 months, but I know what you are saying. This is the same form as the above.

Comment: @bryansis2010. Sorry for the notation : $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Comment: actually you know what? this was explained to me earlier today. It is much better to use the Gamma Distribution to explain this.